# Redux how to update nested state object immutably without useless shallow copies?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

Im using NGRX store on angular project.

This is the state type:

```
export interface TagsMap {
    [key:number]: { // lets call this key - user id.
        [key: number]: number // and this key - tag id.
    }
}
```

So for example:

```
{5: {1: 1, 2: 2}, 6: {3: 3}}
```

User 5 has tags: 1,2, and user 6 has tag 3.

I have above 200k keys in this state, and would like to make the updates as efficient as possible.
The operation is to add a tag to all the users in the state.
I tried the best practice approach like so :

```
const addTagToAllUsers = (state, tagIdToAdd) => {
  const userIds = Object.keys(state.userTags);
  return userIds.reduce((acc, contactId, index) => {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [contactId]: {
        ...acc[contactId],
        [tagIdToAdd]: tagIdToAdd
      }
    };
  }, state.userTags);
};
```

But unfortunately this makes the browser crush when there are over 200k users and around 5 tags each.

I managed to make it work with this:

```
const addTagToAllUsers = (state, tagIdToAdd) => {
  const stateUserTagsShallowCopy = {...state.userTags};
  const userIds = Object.keys(stateUserTags);
  for (let i = 0; i <= userIds.length - 1; i++) {
    const currUserId = userIds[i];
    stateUserTagsShallowCopy[currUserId] = {
      ...stateUserTagsShallowCopy[currUserId],
      [tagIdToAdd]: tagIdToAdd
    };
  }
  return stateUserTagsShallowCopy;
};
```

And the components are updated from the store nicely **without any bugs as far as I checked**.

But as written [here](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-nested-objects): Redux website mentions :

> The key to updating nested data is that every level of nesting must be copied and updated appropriately

Therefore I wonder if my solution is bad.

**Questions:**

1. I Believe I'm still shallow coping all levels in state, am i wrong ?
2. Is it a bad solution? if so what bugs may it produce that I might be missing ?
3. **Why is it required to update sub nested level state in an immutable manner**, if the store selector will still fire because the parent reference indeed changed. (Since it works with **shallow checks on the top level**.)
4. What is the best efficient solution ?

Regarding question 3, here is an example of the selector code :

```
import {createFeatureSelector, createSelector, select} from '@ngrx/store';//ngrx version 10.0.0

//The reducer
const reducers = {
  userTags: (state, action) => {
    //the reducer function..
  }
}

//then on app module: 
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers)

//The selector :
const stateToUserTags = createSelector(
  createFeatureSelector('userTags'),
  (userTags) => {
    //this will execute whenever userTags state is updated, as long as it passes the shallow check comparison.
    //hence the question why is it required to return a new reference to every nested level object of the state...
    return userTags;
  }
)

//this.store is NGRX: Store<State>
const tags$: Observable<any> = this.store.pipe(select(stateToUser))


//then in component I use it something like this: 
<tagsList tags=[tags$ | async]>
</tagsList>
```

Comment: just use helper library. https://immerjs.github.io/immer/produce

Comment: @Robert thanks for the comment, not the ideal solution for me to add a library but if there will not be a better alternative i'll do that, so with this library the solution will be as follows ?

Comment: const nextStore = produce(store, draft => {
  const userIds = Object.keys(draft.userTags);
  for (let i = 0; i <= userIds.length - 1; i++) {
    const currentUserId = userIds[i];
    draft.userTags[currentUserId] = {
      ...draft.userTags[currentUserId],
      [tagIdToAdd]: tagIdToAdd
    }
  }
})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is perfectly fine.
The rule of thumb is that you cannot mutate an object/array stored in `state`.

In Your example, the only thing that You are mutating is the `stateUserTagsShallowCopy` object (it is not stored inside state since it is a shallow copy of `state.userTags`).

Sidenote: It is better to use `for of` here since you don't need to access the index

```
const addTagToAllUsers = (state, tagIdToAdd) => {
  const stateUserTagsShallowCopy = {...state.userTags};
  const userIds = Object.keys(stateUserTags);
  for (let currUserId of userIds) {
    stateUserTagsShallowCopy[currUserId] = {
      ...stateUserTagsShallowCopy[currUserId],
      [tagIdToAdd]: tagIdToAdd
    };
  }
  return stateUserTagsShallowCopy;
};
```

If you decide to use `immer` this will look like this

```
import produce from "immer";

const addTagToAllUsers = (state, tagIdToAdd) => {
  const updatedStateUserTags = produce(state.userTags, draft => {
    for (let draftTags of Object.values(draft)) {
       tags[tagIdToAdd] = tagIdToAdd
    }
  })
  return updatedStateUserTags
});
```

(this comes usually with performance cost). With `immer` you can sacrifice performance to gain readability

ad 3.

> Why is it required to update sub nested level state in an immutable manner, if the store selector will still fire because the parent reference indeed changed. (Since it works with shallow checks on the top level.)

Every store change selectors recompute to see if the dependent component should re-render.

imagine that instead of immutable update of the user tags we decided to mutate tags inside user (`state.userTags` is a new object reference but we mutate (reuse) old entries objects `state.userTags[userId]`)

```
const addTagToAllUsers = (state, tagIdToAdd) => {
  const stateUserTagsShallowCopy = {...state.userTags};
  const userIds = Object.keys(stateUserTags);
  for (let currUserId of userIds) {
    stateUserTagsShallowCopy[currUserId][tagIdToAdd] = tagIdToAdd;
  }
  return stateUserTagsShallowCopy;
};
```

In your case, you have a selector that takes out `state.userTags`.
It means that every time a state update happens `nrgx` will compare the previous result of the selector and the current one (`prevUserTags === currUserTags` by reference). In our case, we change `state.userTags` so the component that uses this selector will be refreshed with new `userTags`.

But imagine other selectors that instead of all `userTags` will select only one user tags. In our imaginary situation, we mutate directly `userTags[someUserId]` so the reference remains the same each time. The negative effect here is that subscribing component will be not refreshed (will not see an update after a tag is added).

Comment: Thanks, any idea maybe regarding question 3? Why is it required to update sub nested level state in an immutable manner, if the store selector will still fire because the parent reference indeed changed. (Since it works with shallow checks on the top level.)

Comment: What is your selector code?

Comment: Using createSelector function of ngrx, I added a full example on the question as you can see above

Comment: I have added update, please let me know is it clear, and if this answers Your question

Comment: Hi, I see yes it answers my questions :) let me just verify with this : So in case the selector is as follows: stateToUserFiveTags = createSelector(
  createFeatureSelector('userTags'),
  (userTags) => {
    return userTags[5];
  }
) and a mutation on userTags[5] will occur, the subscriber for this selector will not be triggered correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly - subscriber won't be triggered because this selector will return the same object reference as before.